# Elastic search query using groupby and having equivalent

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic index with objects of the form:
Connection(t, p, someflag)

I want to get all connections with someflag=true, OR with the following condition:
p exists in two or more connections

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get some proper help you should consider to format your question, and show some actual data to make it easier to understand your data format. Also what have u tried so far to achieve it?

Comment: You should post what you have tied doing and what the problem is you are having. This question is of a low quality you should edit it to make it more clear.